# Green kernel vs fundamental solution

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, lie-groups, laplacian, green-function

Let $L$ being the Laplacian for a given Lie group $G$. I would like to know what is the difference between the two notions in relation to the operator $L$:

- The fundamental solution $\Gamma(x)$ of $L$;
- And the green kernel $\mathcal G(x)$of $L$.

In which case,  we have $\Gamma(x)=\mathcal G(x)$ or the contrary ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: isn't it just that the fundamental solution does not respect the boundary condition, while the Green function does?

Comment: Can we say so, without boundary condition, we have: Fundamental solution=Green kernel?

Comment: yes, that is my understanding.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on fundamental solution says: In mathematics, a fundamental solution for a linear partial differential operator L is a formulation in the language of distribution theory of the older idea of a Green's function, which normally further addresses boundary conditions. Thank you @Beenakker